# How to crop images using Pillow and pytesseract?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

I was trying to use `pytesseract` to find the box positions of each letter in an image. I tried to use an [image](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwQKHaQ89q8P35hVNz-VQDss_nXvqq_SbcOA&usqp=CAU), and cropping it with Pillow and it worked, but when I tried with a lower character size image ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yZ6b.png)), the program may recognize the characters, but cropping the image with the box coordinates give me images like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpLjN.png). I also tried to double up the size of the original image, but it changed nothing.

```
img = Image.open('imgtest.png')
data=pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img)
dati= data.splitlines()
corde=[]
for i in dati[0].split()[1:5]: #just trying with the first character
    corde.append(int(i))
im=img.crop(tuple(corde))
im.save('cimg.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we stick to the source code of [`image_to_boxes`](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/3bae1542e3f586d8c6c9db95fd8c952d69232e13/pytesseract/pytesseract.py#L455), we see, that the returned coordinates are in the following order:

```
left bottom right top
```

From the documentation on [`Image.crop`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop), we see, that the expected order of coordinates is:

```
left upper right lower
```

Now, it also seems, that `pytesseract` iterates images from bottom to top. Therefore, we also need to further convert the `top`/`upper` and `bottom`/`lower` coordinates.

That'd be the reworked code:

```py
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = Image.open('MJwQi9f.png')
data = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img)
dati = data.splitlines()
corde = []
for i in dati[0].split()[1:5]:
    corde.append(int(i))
corde = tuple([corde[0], img.size[1]-corde[3], corde[2], img.size[1]-corde[1]])
im = img.crop(tuple(corde))
im.save('cimg.png')
```

You see, `left` and `right` are in the same place, but `top`/`upper` and `bottom`/`lower` switched places, and where also altered w.r.t. the image height.

And, that's the updated output:

[image: Output]

The result isn't optimal, but I assume, that's due to the font.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
Pillow:        8.1.0
pytesseract:   4.00.00alpha
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, I have noticed this detail but since with big images it was working, i didn't think that the problem was that